# includepdf does not find file with comma

Tags: errors, external-files, pdfpages, naming

I am already using `grffile` to ensure that all files are found on the file system (windows 7), but now I have an example where the second file is not found.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} % 
\usepackage[%
   extendedchars, encoding, multidot, space,
   filenameencoding=latin1, % Windows XP, Vista, 7
]{grffile}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{fonts/fontsample - Latin Modern Family.pdf}
\includepdf{fonts/fontsample - Charter, Bera Sans, Luxi Mono.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The error is

> LaTeX Error: File `fonts/fontsample - Charter' not found.

How can I ensure that a comma is a valid char for a filename in `\includepdf` ?

Comment: The `grffile` package might help. But IMNSHO it's better to avoid filenames like these with TeX.

Comment: Do you really need commas in the filenames ? It's really a *coz' I can* choice. It might cause more trouble even after you figure this one out.

Comment: No i do not. The file names are generated by script that creates these files. But I would be interested in a solution if there is a simple one.

Comment: The `\includepdf` command executes internally `\AM@readlist` that gets as argument a comma separated list; it's probably done for avoiding code duplication with `\includepdfmerge`, but has the effect of not accepting file names with commas.

Comment: Try `\includepdf{{...}}`, i.e., protect the filename in quotes.

Comment: @Aditya Unfortunately, on unix, it ends up looking for a file name including the braces.

Comment: maybe it's easier to modify the part of the script that creates these names?

Answer (score 4):

> The `grffile` package might help. But IMNSHO it's better to avoid filenames like these with TeX.

If you really need such file name you can use:

```
\includepdf{\string"fonts/fontsample - Charter, Bera Sans, Luxi Mono.pdf"}
```