# includepdf and file with comma

Tags: pdftex, punctuation, pdfpages, external-files, filesystem-access

How can I use filenames with commas with pdfpages?

The `grffile` package didn't help, the `\detokenize` command didn't help either

Also the `\string` command doesn't work. For ex.

```
\includepdf{\string"C:/data/tesi/papers_literature_review/stampati/Tyebjee, Bruno - A model of venture capitalist investment activity.pdf"}
```

Gives me:

> Unknown graphics extension: .pdf". ...nture capitalist investment
>   activity.pdf"}

That is to say I have tried any solution of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95900/includepdf-does-not-find-file-with-comma) answer without success

Please don't answer saying that I should not use commas in file names. We are in 2017 and we still have troubles dealing with special characters

Here is a non working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[multidot, extendedchars]{grffile} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[keepaspectratio]{\detokenize{C:/data/tesi/papers_literature_review/stampati/Tyebjee, Bruno - A model of venture capitalist investment activity.pdf}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use commas in file names. And, yes: I read carefully your question.

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem is with `\includepdf`, because `\includegraphics` seems to work.

Comment: @egreg pdfpages does `\AM@setphantomdoc #1,#2\END ` in its code. So the comma is a stop marker. (As far as I can see is it part of the code to resort page, e.g. for booklets and there are more comma lists  involved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includepdf}{O{}m}
  {
   \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
   \tl_replace_all:Nnf \l_tmpa_tl { , } { \char_generate:nn { `, } { 11 } }
   \ORIincludepdf[#1]{\l_tmpa_tl}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The problem is that `pdfpages` uses the code for splitting the options also for managing the file name and so problems are to be expected when there is a comma in the file name. Indeed, it turns out that the file is loaded correctly, but when it's time to *use* it, the problem appears.

This can be cured by changing the commas in the file name into characters with different category code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multidot, extendedchars]{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro}

% save the original macro    
\LetLtxMacro\ORIincludepdf\includepdf

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includepdf}{O{}m}
 {
  % store the file name as a string
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
  % replace commas (catcode 12) with commas (catcode 11)
  \tl_replace_all:Nnf \l_tmpa_tl { , } { \char_generate:nn { `, } { 11 } }
  \ORIincludepdf[#1]{\l_tmpa_tl}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nnf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\includepdf[keepaspectratio,pages={-}]{file, with space, and comma.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice --- although that "actualize the change" seems a bit black magic... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Replaced one black magic with another.

Answer (score 9):

Even in 2017, putting spaces and commas in filenames is a bad idea, however

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\typeout{===}
{\catcode`\,=11    \includepdf{abc,xyz}}
\typeout{===}
\end{document}
```

works as seen in the log:

```
===
[1 <./abc,xyz.pdf{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdf
tex.map}>]
===
```

Or if you really need a punctuation comma at the same time

```
{\catcode`\,=11 \gdef\zz{abc,xyz}}   \includepdf[keepaspectratio, pages={-}]{\zz}
```

Comment: It does not work if you use the comma to separate options of pdfpages `{\catcode\`\,=11    \includepdf[keepaspectratio, pages={-}]{C:/data/tesi/papers_literature_review/stampati/Tyebjee, Bruno - A model of venture capitalist investment activity.pdf}}`

Comment: yep, you can't have the cake and eat it too ;-)... I agree with @egreg here. Why castigate oneself using these filenames? You could use your `bibtex` keys for the filenames, for example, and forget about that. In a case of an emergency, just create a link...

Comment: @raffamaiden updated for that case (but just renaming the file not to have a comma is easier)

Comment: @Rmano self eating cake supplied:-)