# LaTeX: How can I escape arbitrary text as a literal string?

Tags: macros, strings

I have a build system for my latex files that injects some environment variables into the latex file that is to be compiled.

Usually, the environment variables contain path to image files. So, a build system may generate a TeX file that looks like:

```
\newcommand{\myfilepath}{/folder/file.png}
```

And later on, it may be used such as:

```
\includegraphics{\myfilepath}
```

But, this breaks if the file path `/folder/file.png` contains special characters.

How can I write the TeX code generation program in a way that makes the `\includegraphics` line works?

Comment: You might want to escape characters that have a special meaning in TeX, that is `{` `}` `$` `_` `^` `#` `&` `\ ` `~` and `%`. Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/47927

Comment: Are you inputting `VAR_VALUE` somewhere or is it being automatically generated? In the former case, put the escapes in when setting it. In the latter case, it probably depends on the details of how exactly it's generated.

Comment: You could write `\newcommand{\varname}{\texttt{\detokenize{$VAR_VALUE}}}` for the value, but you can't really have `$VAR_NAME` as macro name (well, you could, but you shouldn't).

Comment: @JasperHabicht Indeed, this is what I was doing. But using `\_` instead of `_` actually broke the build. It seems that `_` does NOT need to be escaped in `\newcommand{name}{...}`. Can someone shed any info on this?

Comment: @campa I thought `\texttt` is for formatting a text as monospace? I just want to escape the text. `VAR_NAME`s generally are well-behaved and do not need escaping.

Comment: @cfr `VAL_VALUE` is manually inputted by myself, but not in relation to LaTeX. E.g., I have `export DEP_LOGO=~/../logo.png`. I could manually escape all these, but I am looking for an automated solution. An automated solution will allow me to incrementally automate more and more, so it's worth it even if it is overkill for my current needs.

Comment: @HappyFace If you plan to use the image, as opposed to typesetting the path, you probably don't need or want to escape it. I don't do anything special when processing paths and I have quite a lot of code involving this kind of configuration. If you escape things, I'm not sure the result will work as you expect and you certainly don't *need* to escape things for it to work in e.g. `\includegraphics` or `\graphicspath` or `\includepdf` etc.

Comment: If your build system replaces the placeholders correctly, then what needs to be done really depends on what you are doing with the variable once it is defined.

Comment: `\detokenize` is your friend here.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. So my current understanding is that special chars like `_` behave differently when they are the argument of `\includegraphics`. Is there a documentation page that explains this behavior? Some characters will need to be escaped even in that context though, e.g., `{}`? Is `\detokenize` useful here?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, that question is about (manually) typesetting some arbitrary text. I want to set some variables with an arbitrary string, not typeset anything. I also need the solution to be automated in some programming language.

Comment: Do you really have `{}` in the names of files and directories? In general, you should avoid using special characters in file and directory names irrespective of the current question. An underscore would normally need escaping, but I don't do anything special when it's part of a directory name I'm passing to `\includegraphics` or `\file_input:n` or whatever. Note that it really isn't clear what you are trying to do or what you mean by 'automated in some programming language'. Indeed, that doesn't sound like a question for this site ....

Comment: LaTeX can do different things. E.g., It can do typesetting whereby characters of category 11 and 12  of the .tex-input-file are directives for choosing a glyph of a font or to construct a symbol from several glyphes. E.g., it can write things to screen or external text file. E.g., wwhen processing a command `\input` or `\includegraphics`, it can take sequences of characters for filenames. Thus the kind of escaping depends on what is to be done wih the characters in question.

Comment: What you can do is having TeX read the characters in question in verbatim-catcode-régime and then change the catcode-régime appropriately for the task in question where the characters are to be processed and then apply `\scantokens` to the characters previously read in verbatim catcode-régime.

Comment: @HappyFace your question is still very unclear what you mean by escape or in what context. for example `_`,  `{}` , `$` need no special treatment in `\includegraphics`, but `~` would need `\string~`  so `\includegraphics{\string~/aaa_b#.png}` should work fine as would `\includegraphics{\detokenize{~/aaa_b#.png}}` with the latter being easier for automated situations as you can always apply it to the whole string.

Comment: If things are needed only in the context of file names and file paths, then with primitives like `\read`, `\openin`, `\openout`, `\input` (which is renamrd to `\@@input` in LaTeX) afaik only characters that usually have one of the category codes 0(escape) - backslash, 7(superscript) - `^`,  9(ignored), 10(space) - space and horizontal tab, 13(active) - `~`, 14(comment) - `%` or 15(ignored)  require special attention. In case of processing file names/file paths inside tables, characters of category 4(alignment tab) - `&`, require special attention as well.

Comment: With macros like `\includegraphics` characters of category 1(begin group) - `{` and characters of category 2(end group) - `}` need special treatment as well so that they can make it into an undelimited macro argument. If using `\detokenize` or the like, characters of category 6(parameter) - `#` - also need special treatment for avoiding them to be doubled.

Comment: Basically it is a mess. [How to \include files with commas in their path - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623195/how-to-include-files-with-commas-in-their-path) [characters - allowable filenames for source files - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59367/allowable-filenames-for-source-files) [input - How to make \include work with a quoted string path containing spaces? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/how-to-make-include-work-with-a-quoted-string-path-containing-spaces)

Comment: The practical solution is to use the external program to copy/create a symbolic link of your desired file to something with nice name, then include that instead. The non-practical solution is to delve deep into the *source code* of TeX and LaTeX to see how exactly things are implemented and which special characters break, and how to workaround it. (to the best of my knowledge, high level commands like `\includegraphics` *officially* does not support special character in file name and tell the user to rename the files.

Comment: The official documentation is in e.g. the LaTeX companion, which is a textbook which you need to buy.)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, you can submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks. I indeed only want `\includegraphics` and `\input` to work with these. You can turn your comments into an answer. I am still a bit confused about how each of the special characters you have enumerated should be escaped. Does `\includegraphics{\detokenize{A}}` where `A` is my path that has been processed to have escaped `{}` with `\{` and `\}` work?